# Save information in local Storage

Tags: android, realm, android-storage

I'm using realm(also tried sharepreference) to save some information.But When I cleared app's data,All information has removed.
I have one question.How I can save some information to my device,witch always 'll be in storage? (if i cleared data or uninstalled my app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, clearing local data delete shared preferences and data in the local SQL Lite database as well. However you can make a folder for your app in local SD card or in phone's internal storage. These folders will not be deleted even if your app uninstalled. In these folders you can store your data in some sort of a format, it maybe in plain text or it maybe some encrypted files. It's your call.. hope this helps

Comment: If I uninstall my App,then what's happend? I want to create and save information always @Infamous

Comment: Well the folder you create in the internal storage or in the external SD card will continue to exist even after uninstallation of your App with all the data you have saved in those folders.. these are called public folders Android also provides private files in external storage which will be deleted if and when the app is uninstalled.. check out this link https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html